# How can I loop through all checked checkboxes in jQuery, getting their value in each loop?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, meteor, spacebars

I have this HTML/Spacebars in a Meteor template:

```
<label for="seljoblocs">Select the Jobs/Locations for the selected Worker</label>
<div id="seljoblocs" name="seljoblocs">
  {{#each jobLocs}}
    <input type="checkbox" value={{jl_jobloc}}><label>{{jl_jobloc}}</label>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

This generates a checkbox for each "jobloc" via the Helper function:

```
jobLocs: function() {
  return JobLocations.find({}, {
    sort: {
      jl_jobloc: 1
    },
    fields: {
      jl_jobloc: 1
    }
  });
}
```

I have this jQuery for that template's form submit event:

```
'submit form': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var workerid = template.find('#selworker').value;

    Meteor.call('insertWorkerJobLocLookup', workerid, jobloc, function(err)          
    {
      if (err) {
        Session.set("lastErrMsg", err.message);
      } else {
        console.log(workerid + ' for ' + jobloc + ' inserted');
      } // else
    }); // Meteor call

    $('#selworker').val("");
    // TODO: Uncheck all the checkboxes
}
```

I need to loop through all the checked checkboxes, calling the 'insertWorkerJobLocLookup' method once for each checked checkbox, something like this (pseudocode):

```
'submit form': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var workerid = template.find('#selworker').value;

    foreach (checked checkbox czech) {
        var jobLocation = czech.value;
        Meteor.call('insertWorkerJobLocLookup', workerid, jobLocation, 
function(err) {
          if (err) {
            Session.set("lastErrMsg", err.message);
          } else {
            console.log(workerid + ' for ' + jobloc + ' inserted');
          } // else
        }); // Meteor call           
    }
    $('#selworker').val("");
    // TODO: Uncheck all the checkboxes
}
```

This portion:

```
foreach (checked checkbox czech) {
    var jobLocation = czech.value;
```

...of the pseudocode is where I have no clue what to do to first loop through the checked checkboxes, and then get the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(index){
  //part where the magic happens
  console.log(index+' checkbox has value' +$(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sindis' idea worked; this works:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(index) {
  var workerid = template.find('#selworker').value;
  var jobloc = $(this).val();

  Meteor.call('insertWorkerJobLocLookup', workerid, jobloc, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      Session.set("lastErrMsg", err.message);
    } else {
      console.log(workerid + ' for ' + jobloc + ' inserted');
    } // else
  }); // Meteor call
});
```